# Leading align behaviour?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am giving leading align constraint for two label. When text in both the lebel is same both liked aligned properly. But if text is different they don't look aligned (Difference of 1 Pixel is coming), is there any constraint, that work independently of text.??[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Post and This Screen?  They look aligned to me.  Make sure you do not have a constant of 1 in your constraint.  You can check their position by printing the origin.x value of each label in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method.